# Difference for two ways of using React props

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference for the two below? People seem to prefer using **'1'**.

#### 1.

```
const {dispatch} = this.props
dispatch(userListRequest({}))
```

#### 2.

```
this.props.dispatch(userListRequest({}))
```

Comment: No difference, the first just makes for less code to write and read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the functionality of your code in both approaches. Approach 1 is called `destructuring` which is useful when you need to extract multiple values from a single object as it eliminates the need to write repetitive code to get multiple values from an object. For example, suppose your object looks like the following:

```
const myObj = {firstName: "Telepresence", lastName: "Stackoverflow"}
```

Then, you can directly unpack/extract all the values of `myObj` in a single line as follows:

```
const { firstName, lastName } = myObj
```

instead of getting these values using `myObj.firstName` and `myObj.lastName`. Overall, destructuring helps in writing clean and readable code while reducing repetition of code.

Answer (score 1):

This case means creating variable dispatch with using destructuration of the props object. This way is preferable to use when you have a lot of different properties in the props object, but you need only one or a few.

```
const {dispatch} = this.props;
dispatch(userListRequest({}));
```

This case means to call dispatch property explicitly from the props object.

```
this.props.dispatch(userListRequest({}));
```

P.S. On both cases result will be same.